# Calculating current a capacitor can deliver

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, coil, solenoid

I made a simple coilgun circuit

- Capacitor 50 V 10000 uF
- DC power supply of 20 V - 5 A
- Coil of enamelled wire 18 AWG - 3.5 ohm

[image]

[image]

My calculations according to Ohm's law the current in the capacitor should be:

20 V (capacitor voltage after charged) / 3.5 ohms (resistance) = 5.7 A in the circuit

Why do I only between 1.5 to 2.2 A?

Comment: Too short pulse for your current clamp to capture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much current can a capacitor deliver?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631333/how-much-current-can-a-capacitor-deliver)

Comment: 10mF with 3.5 ohms means capacitor will discharge 99% in 0.175 seconds. Do you expect the meter to measure that?

Comment: @vir it is different circuit, and the question here is why did not gives 5.7A?!

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/2h67kq3v This is probably what your circuit looks like. Notice the (guessed) internal resistance of the capacitor and (guessed) inductance of the coil

Answer (score 3):

1. Your clamp meter can't capture the peak fast enough.
2. The current depends on the impedance of the coil, not just the resistance.
3. The current depends in the internal resistance of the capacitor as well as its impedance.

Your calculated current is probably incorrect, and your meter probably can't capture the real current because it changes too fast.

Comment: Should i calculate Impedance of coil in DC circuit?! Can you demonstrate how to calculate the impedance in this circuit ?

Comment: It isn't a DC circuit.  It's a circuit with a current step and an LC (inductor and capacitor) resonant tank.

Comment: You have to measure the inductance and the internal resistance of the coil.  You have to measure the internal resistance of the capacitor.  You can use the capacitor value.

Comment: I don't know the equations you would need.  I do know that your clamp meter won't be able to accurately measure it.

Comment: That clamp meter scale is **~AC**, not peak reading. It is perhaps assuming sinusoidal current and trying to scale it to look like RMS current. And its doing *that* to a decaying waveshape. The decaying waveshape is most likely sinusoidal, of an unknown frequency, because coil inductance is not known. The displayed result is mostly meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Shown below is current that flows through the coil after the "launch" switch is closed.

Coil inductance is not known, but coil resistance is very likely near 3.5 ohms - it is a relatively easy thing to measure. 3.5 ohms is assumed to be the dominant resistance in the capacitor's discharge path, and is held constant for all five plots. Capacitance is 10,000 microfarads and is assumed charged initially to 20V:
[image: charged capacitor discharge versus time into an inductor with 3.5 ohms series resistance]

You can see that coil inductance greatly influences how current flows after the capacitor begins discharging. Note too, that maximum current occurs *after* the switch closes. One is most likely only interested in that first current peak, and the time when it occurs. 
For the 0.03H coil, peak current occurs 16ms after switch closes (switch closes at the 0.1 second point). Current falls to near-zero about 0.1 second after switch closes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the capacitor current behaves if the inductance is 1 H. You can see that at 3.5s the current is essentially zero. The clamp meter cannot measure this.

[image]